# DEVICE_CREDENTIAL dosent work if fingerprint is there

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt

So I have been working on implementing an authentication feature in my app so first I implemented Fingerprint authentication it works perfectly. But now am trying to add an option for pin too I have added that option with the help of documentation in the android developer

link
https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth

So now the problem is I have implemented but in-app when I use fingerprint it works fine but when I use pin it doesn't work as nothing happens. But the pin actually works when there is no fingerprint saved on the device

So here's the code

```
firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    if (firebaseUser != null) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Authentication", 0);
        String bio = sharedPreferences.getString(TEXT, "");



    if (bio.equals("1")) {

        BiometricManager biometricManager = androidx.biometric.BiometricManager.from(this);
        switch (biometricManager.canAuthenticate(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_WEAK | DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)) {

            // this means we can use biometric sensor
            case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS:

                break;

            // this means that the device doesn't have fingerprint sensor
            case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE:

                break;

            // this means that biometric sensor is not available
            case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE:

                break;

            // this means that the device doesn't contain your fingerprint
            case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED:

                break;
            case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_SECURITY_UPDATE_REQUIRED:
                break;
            case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED:

                break;
            case BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_STATUS_UNKNOWN:

                break;
        }
        // creating a variable for our Executor
        Executor executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this);
        // this will give us result of AUTHENTICATION
        final BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(StartActivity.this, executor, new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode, @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
                super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);
            }

            // THIS METHOD IS CALLED WHEN AUTHENTICATION IS SUCCESS
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(@NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
                super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
                super.onAuthenticationFailed();
            }
        });
        // creating a variable for our promptInfo
        // BIOMETRIC DIALOG
        final BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder().setTitle("Authentication")
                .setDescription("Use your fingerprint to login ")
                .setAllowedAuthenticators(BiometricManager.Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_WEAK|DEVICE_CREDENTIAL).build();

        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);

    }else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

I hope these are enough information for my problem

Comment: Was this resolved for you?

Comment: No I just gave up :(